# fullcalendar dayClick off by one day

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar 3.3.1 in a C# .Net project.

I define the calendar

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    'header': {
        'left': "prev,next today",
        'center': "title",
        'right': "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
    },
    'dayClick': function (myDate, jsEvent, view) {
        var tmpDate = moment(myDate.format());

        if (view.name !== "agendaDay") {
            console.log("clicked on non agendaDay: " + tmpDate.format());
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar("gotoDate", tmpDate.format());
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar("changeView", "agendaDay");
        } else {
            console.log("clicked on agendaDay");
        }
    },
    ...
```

By default the web page shows a `month` view.  Clicking on a day block (actually in any view except `agendaDay`) will take you to the `agendaDay` view for the date clicked... or it should.  It was doing this this morning but it has now stopped.  It now takes me to "today" regardless of the date I click.

I've tested this in a fiddle but it works there.  I can see the expected date in the `console.log`.  I can use the Chrome developer tools and set a break-point on the `gotoDate` call and I can see the correct date but the end result is "today".

I was using the `myDate` argument directly, which is a `moment` object, but that was not working.  I decided to use the `tmpDate` variable to make sure something was not changing the date out from under me.

What am I missing?

**Edit**  For the heck of it I reversed the order of the `gotoDate` and `changeView` calls, it now sets the date of the new view correctly.  Go figure

Comment: Sounds like something is overriding the event handler for `today`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing view resets your date to today.

You should either [changeView](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/changeView/) and then gotoDate or if you'd like to navigate to a new date while simultaneously switching to a new view, you can specify a date parameter like so:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay', '2017-06-01');
```

Here is working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4a1qyan/).